# Настройка Sublime Text 3 под Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ide, sublime-text, settings

Решил перейти на Sublime столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Установленные packages:

1. Python3
2. Sublime PuthonIDE
3. All Autocomplite
4. Sublime CodeIntel
5. SublimeREPL

При запуске любого кода на python в sublime выдаёт:

> "py" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
> ��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
> [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
> [shell_cmd: py -3 -OO -u "D:\Programming\Python\Learning\Programm Deal List\test.py"]
> [dir: D:\Programming\Python\Learning\Programm Deal List]
> [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\programdata\oracle\java\javapath;c:\program files (x86)\amd app\bin\x86_64;c:\program files (x86)\amd app\bin\x86;c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\wbem;c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0;c:\program files\dotnet;c:\program files\nvidia corporation\nvidia nvdlisr;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common]

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле причин может быть много, типа неправильной установки/настройки дополнений или их конфликтность друг с другом. Например чтобы Sublime CodeIntel работал, нужно предварительно установить CodeIntel в питоне.
Однако и без этого набор плагинов, мягко говоря не очень:

- Sublime PuthonIDE - не обновлялся уже пять лет
- All Autocomplite - пытается обхватить необъятное
- Sublime CodeIntel - тоже 3 года как в коме
- из всего списка SublimeREPL еще более менее, но тоже требует настройки.

Вместо всего этого лучше установить:

- Для подсветки ошибок - [Sublime Linter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter), который имеет отдельный модуль для работы с питоном [SublimeLinter-pylint](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-pylint) (в самом питоне должен быть установлен [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/))
- Для автодополнения и навигации по определениям - [Jedi - Python autocompletion](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Jedi%20-%20Python%20autocompletion)
- Для запуска кода (вместо репла) и работы с терминалами - [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus)

В принципе этого вполне достаточно для комфортной работы с кодом, особенно если вникнуть и настроить под себя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]